# Batch file FOR /f tokens not looping

Tags: loops, for-loop, batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file to sort some pdf to respective directory. eg. xxx1_date.pdf to DIR1, xxx2_date.pdf to DIR2. Below are my code taken from one a script I found in this site. Thank you.

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

dir /b /a-d *.pdf > file.log

for /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %%f in (file.log) do (
    set line=%%f
    call :processToken
    )
goto :eof

:processToken
for /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %%a in ("%line%") do (
        IF "%%a"=="04693139" move %%a* DIR1
        IF "%%a"=="34051646" move %%a* DIR2
    )
if not "%line%" == "" goto :processToken
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `file.log` should contain lines, eg:

```
xxx1_date1.pdf
xxx2_date2.pdf
```

The first loop would assign `xxx1` to `%%f`, then to `line` and process it; then
assign `xxx2` to `%%f`, then to `line` and process *that*.

"Token 1" is the string up to the first `_` (the delimiter) and is assigned to `%%f`.
"Token *" is the string after the first `_` (the delimiter) and is assigned to `%%g`.

Since `line` contains `xxx1` and `xxx2`, the next `for` will assign `xxx1`, `xxx2` to `%%a` and *nothing* to `%%b` since the delimiter is again `_`.

Since neither `xxx1` nor `xxx2` matches to two date strings, the `move` will not take place.

Regardless, `line` is not being changed and is not *empty*, so the `if not ...` will **always** be true, and you will enter an endless loop.

Now you *could* fix your code once you realise what portions of you filename will appear where, or you could do the task by simply executing

```
move *_04693139.pdf DIR1
move *_34051646.pdf DIR2
```